# Central administration sharepoint 2010 in iis

Tags: sharepoint

I'm getting error when I access central administration in sharepoint because central administration in IIS service has been delete. how to restore it?

I try to create manually in IIS and use default port 41560 of central administration, but still failed to access central administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the psconfig.exe tool to provision a new Central Admin site. Example: psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -provision -port 41560 -windowsauthprovider onlyusentlm

More info here, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093(v=office.14).aspx